# Licensing Javascript Components

Tags: javascript, licensing

I have a based doubt how the licensing of javascript based components work.

I have see some fancy javascript products which are licensed gives a full demo version to playaround. Now if the demo version code is fully functional what stops the user from using it in production r without paying the license fee? Is there a way we can check who uses our product without proper license?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"what stops the user from using it in production without paying the license fee?"

1. Honesty
2. With client-side code, the fact that it's very easy to get caught breaking the rules.

Comment: would like to elaborate on point 2. to clarify which ways there are for the asker:  "Is there a way we can check who uses our product without proper license?"